# How do I add numbers to an array and display them in assembly 8086?

Tags: arrays, assembly, emu8086, low-level

so, I'm still a beginner in assembly.
I was trying to make a program where it takes IDs and add them to an array, could be one ID or more depending on the partners in the group.
my problem is: I don't think I'm adding the IDs to the array the right way, when I try to display them I get 0 even after I enter the digits

The problem is not with dispalying, it is most likely with inserting to the array.
this is my code:

```
.model small
.stack 100

.data
    IDs         DB 20 DUP(7)     ; Array to store the IDs (7 digits each)
    IDCount     DB 0             ; Number of IDs entered
    prompt1     DB 0Dh, 0Ah, "Enter your ID (7 digits): $"
    prompt2     DB 0Dh, 0Ah, "Do you have partners in your team? (y for Yes/n for No): $"
    prompt3     DB 0Dh, 0Ah, "Enter partner ID (7 digits) $"
    menu        DB 0Dh, 0Ah, "Menu:", 0Dh, 0Ah
                DB "1. Display IDs", 0Dh, 0Ah
                DB "2. Exit", 0Dh, 0Ah
                DB "Enter your choice: $"
    result      DB 0Dh, 0Ah, "IDs: $"

.code
START:
    MOV AX, @data                   ; Initialize data segment
    MOV DS, AX

CollectIDs:
    ; Collect the ID
    MOV AH, 9
    MOV DX, OFFSET prompt1
    INT 21h

    ; Read the ID from the user
    MOV AH, 1
    MOV CX, 7                       ; Read 7 characters
    MOV AL, IDCount
    MOV DI, OFFSET IDs
    ADD DI, AX
    ADD DI, AX                      ; Multiply IDCount by 2 to skip a cell for each ID

    ReadIDLoop:
        INT 21h
        MOV [DI], AL
        INC DI
        LOOP ReadIDLoop

    INC IDCount

    ; Display the question "Do you have partners in your team?"
    MOV AH, 9
    MOV DX, OFFSET prompt2
    INT 21h

    ; Read the response from the user
    MOV AH, 1
    INT 21h

    ; Check if there are more partners
    CMP AL, 'Y'
    JE CollectIDs
    CMP AL, 'y'
    JE CollectIDs

DisplayMenu:
    ; Display the menu
    MOV AH, 9
    MOV DX, OFFSET menu
    INT 21h

    ; Read the choice from the user
    MOV AH, 1
    INT 21h

    ; Check the user's choice
    CMP AL, '1'
    JE DisplayIDs
    CMP AL, '2'
    JE ExitProgram

    JMP DisplayMenu

DisplayIDs:
    ; Display the collected IDs
    MOV AH, 9
    MOV DX, OFFSET result
    INT 21h

    MOV CL, IDCount               ; Store the IDCount in CL
    MOV SI, OFFSET IDs

    DisplayLoop:
        MOV DL, [SI]
        ADD DL, '0'
        MOV AH, 2
        INT 21h

        ADD SI, 2                   ; Skip a cell
        DEC CL                      ; Decrement the counter
        JNZ DisplayLoop             ; Jump to DisplayLoop if CL is not zero

    JMP DisplayMenu


END START
```

here is what the output look like:
[image: code]

Comment: For starters, you know that `AX` is made up of `AH` and `AL`, right? So what is your `MOV AH, 1` trying to do? It will make `AX` offset by 256 which you then double so you will not be writing in the proper place.

Comment: @Jester yes, you are correct. I'm still a little confused though. how should I implement the collectIDs part so it puts them in an array?

Comment: Also `20 DUP(7)` doesn't do what you want (presumably). It allocates 20 bytes of value 7. I assume you wanted 20*7 bytes. Why are you scaling by 2? If you use a fixed ID size, you should be scaling by 7 but you don't even have to bother since you can just store the IDs consecutively. During printing you can insert a separator after every 7 digits.